# Syntax error with ng-show: "token 'false' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}]"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-show

I'm using `ng-show` as shown below:

```
<data-ng-show={{entity.primary}}===true>
```

The value of `entity.primary` can be either `true` or `false`. I am getting the following error in the console:

> Syntax Error: Token 'false' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

How can this error be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, your code is a concentrate of errors:

1. The `ngShow` directive can only be used as an attribute, and not as an element, as shown by [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#usage) and [the code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/11f5aeeee952a395edaf54e3277674f211a82fc7/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L160).
2. The `ngShow` directive [expects an "expression"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#animations), which is (by and large) standard JavaScript code: you don't need additional curly brackets.
3. Since you're using an equal sign `=` in your attribute, quotes are mandatory around its value, as explained by [this W3C note](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#attr-value-unquoted).

Therefore, the correct code is:

```
<div data-ng-show="entity.primary === true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`ng-show` evaluates an expression. you don't need braces.

try this:

```
<data-ng-show="entity.primary"></div>
```

or this:

```
<data-ng-show="entity.primary === true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add expressions inside the curly braces but not for ng-show `<data-ng-show="entity.primary === true"></div>`.

However ng-show evaluates to either true or false depending on it's set value, so you should just do this
`<data-ng-show="entity.primary"></div>`

And if you need to display the values, you could just add this somewhere

`<div>{{entity.primary}}</div>`
=> returns true or false or whatever value assigned to it.